# Improve JOINED SQL Query efficiency

Tags: mysql, indexing, entity-attribute-value

I have a SQL query which is taking a long time to load.
I think I need to add some indexes but I'm not sure what indexes I should add.

This is the main SQL that is executed:
SQL FIddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f440e2/1

This can take up to and beyond 10 seconds when there is > 20000 records

What indexing would you suggest to improve efficiency?

EXPLAIN Results:

[image]

EXPLAIN Results After Modifications:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running an EXPLAIN on the query? If so, edit your question and post the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add 2 more index in your tables.

```
ALTER TABLE `OpenROData` ADD INDEX key_value_idx (key_value);
ALTER TABLE `OpenRONotes` ADD INDEX ro_number_idx (ro_number);
```

Comment: Thank you. I added those and the same SQL query has gone from average 8-10 seconds to < 1 second. that's fantastic

Comment: @php-b-grader consider updating your question to show the results of the new EXPLAIN